# In Snowflake, or SQL Server, how do I order results in the same order as my query?

Tags: sql-server, order-by, snowflake

In Snowflake, I'm querying the Information_Schema for the number of columns in each of a series of listed tables. How do I write my query so that Snowflake will return the results in the same order that I've listed the table names in the query? I tried CASE WHEN 'table1' THEN 1, CASE WHEN 'table2' THEN 2,...etc, but had no luck. Alternatively, if SQL Server has a better solution for this, I could query it there.

Comment: What is stopping me from asking questions in as user friendly a way as I would like to ask them has been my inability to figure out this site's mark-up language. This is apparently more difficult than SQL. Every time I think I understand how to post code on this site, I get it wrong; it comes out as regular text; and then I get berated and voted down by the moderators. And just from leaving this message I'll probably be voted down. And yes, I've read the pages on how to post.

Comment: Markdown help is available at https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Honestly, markdown doesn't appear to be the issue with your Post here. The clarity of *what* you're actually asking is the issue. Having a little more clearer information such as the table definition(s), some sample data, expected results, and the full query you wrote / are stuck on would've gone a long way here.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback J.D. But some of this I wouldn't necessarily want to add because I'm working with a client's data. I usually change the table and database names to be generic.

Comment: @Jimbo That's fine, but a mechanic can't fix your car if you don't show him the car. All of the information I added can be anonymized if needed, before providing. It's just to get a better picture of what we're working with. Also just a heads up, if you want to notify someone of your comment you can use the `@` before their name. I didn't realize you replied to me until I manually went back to this Post to check.

Comment: @J.D. Ah, got it. Ok, thank you J.D.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Snowflake instance at hand, but since you've tagged it with SQL server as well…

You can provide your filter in a table expression (or temp table or table variable) along with a column used for ordering (called *Ordinal* in my example).

[DB fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/I8aZH0Kz)

```sql
SELECT 
    d.name
    , d.database_id
    , v.Ordinal
FROM sys.databases AS d
JOIN (
    VALUES 
        (1, 'model')
        , (2, 'msdb')
        , (3, 'master')
        , (4, 'tempdb')
) v (Ordinal, dbName)
    ON d.name = v.dbName
ORDER BY v.Ordinal
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I can order the results of my query in the same order as my query with a series of case statements, putting `END` at the end of each case statement:

```
CASE WHEN table_name =  'my_table1' THEN 1 END, 
CASE WHEN table_name = 'my_table2' THEN 2 END,
```

etc.